# Is asking for the best joke one has heard about philosophy appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

I am curious whether people consider the recent question about jokes  [What is the best philosophy joke you have heard.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/52677/29944) to be fitting for this site.

It appears to me to be broad and primarily opinion based although interesting.

Comment: No. Absolutely not. This site has a problem when two users of 3K and 11K rep answered that question instead of voting to close it.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the site if people with high reputation answer the question and do not vote to close it. They can choose to do as they please. They do not have to agree with me.  I just don't think such questions fit on this site.

Comment: It's indicating that they're either unaware of the site standards or actively disregarding them. If they want to answer such questions they should make a strong case that such questions are not off-topic before they do so.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with philosophy being entertaining and accessible to everybody. What's the point in communicating when you are doing it an rancid, boring, cryptic ,corny, condescending old-fashioned way?  Depth can be accessed in multiple ways. Everything evolves even philosophy.

Comment: @PbxMan I agree with you about philosophy in general. However, I don't think that is appropriate for a question and answer site (whether about philosophy or any other topic) which is different from a philosophy forum where anything philosophical can be discussed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use chat for this. Questions should have a relatively objectively determinable "best" answer (which can then be accepted).